# Unable to connect to iFolder server

Tags: 10.10, networking, server, 64-bit, ifolder

I tried to install  [iFolder](http://ifolder.com/ifolder) on Ubuntu 10.10 server 64 bit using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iFolderInstall).

Everything "worked" except: If I try to acccess the server with `http://myurl/admin` I get the error-message "Unable to connect to the iFolder server."

Has anyone succeeded with this guide, or is there an iFolder specialist who could help me with the last steps?

**Update 1**: I could connect to the `/admin`-Interface by not changin anything in the config-script. Changing the ServerName in anything else than `localhost` brings back the error. And changing username and/or password has no affect.

Comment: This question is abandoned, if you feel this is in error, the please flag explaining why and the moderators will reopen it. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you rerun the simias-server-setup you need to delete the simias data folder. this will also delete any users and their files so be sure.

which config script?

why and what are you changing the server name to?

this tut is for opensuse but it may help you out: http://www.daniellench.com/2010/08/ifolder-on-opensuse-11-3/

check out the irc channel on irc.ifolder.net #ifolder
i like the pidgin client for irc

good luck,
dan